# Python filter noise data out of dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Full disclosure, I am extremely new to python (am a C++/C# dev).

I have a list of tuples, each containing a one of 2 message ids, time, and value. The list is sorted by time ascending. In the real data, the time is an integer represented by seconds since epoch (i can replace if that adds clarity). I'd like to be able to pare down the list so that for every entry of Message ID 2, I find the most recent Message ID 1 that is in the list prior.

I have the data converted using pandas, if that aids in the ability to filter down.

```py
data_set = []
data_set.append((1, '12:14', 2.0))
data_set.append((1, '12:15', 42.0))
data_set.append((1, '12:16', 4.0))
data_set.append((2, '12:16', 2.0))
data_set.append((2, '12:17', 2.0))
data_set.append((2, '12:17', 3.0))
data_set.append((1, '12:17', 3.0))
data_set.append((2, '12:18', 18.0))
data_set.append((1, '12:19', 6.0))
```

After paring down, my list would look like this:

```
1, 12:16, 4.0
2, 12:16, 2.0
2, 12:17, 2.0
2, 12:17, 3.0
1, 12:17: 3.0
2, 12:18, 18.0
```

Comment: Is the list sorted by time ?

Comment: `12:14` is invalid syntax. Do you mean `'12:14'` (i.e. a string)? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @InSync - corrected original question and added some additional information regarding the time

Comment: What about your code? SO is not a code writing service. This problem is quite easy and doesn't require anything more than a loop and some conditions, whose syntax you can easily learn by reading a basic guide.

Comment: Is it possible to encounter two consecutive `id==2` in the sequence? If so, then what's your behavior in this case? i.g. what's the output for the sequence `[(1, '12:16'),(2, '12:17'),(2, '12:18')]`?

Comment: @Vitalizzare - Yeah. The id==1 comes in at 10Hz, the id== 2 comes in sporadically, but around 2Hz. The trick is there are multiple sources providing id==1, then you'd see multiple id==2 messages together.

Comment: @InSync - I'm well aware of what SO is. However, the best i could come up was pulling data sets out and finding when id==2 messages came in in groups. I did not consider this a realistic solution, so i opted not to provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is already sorted by date.

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)

# is the first column a 2?
m = df[0].eq(2)

# keep this rows and also the ones before
out = df[m | m.shift(-1)]
```

Output:

```
   0      1     2
2  1  12:16   4.0
3  2  12:16   2.0
4  2  12:17   2.0
5  2  12:17   3.0
6  1  12:17   3.0
7  2  12:18  18.0
```

For a pure python approach:

```
out = []
for i in range(1, len(data_set)):
    if data_set[i][0]==2:
        if data_set[i-1][0]!=2:
            out.append(data_set[i-1])
        out.append(data_set[i])
```

Output:

```
[(1, '12:16', 4.0),
 (2, '12:16', 2.0),
 (2, '12:17', 2.0),
 (2, '12:17', 3.0),
 (1, '12:17', 3.0),
 (2, '12:18', 18.0)]
```

Comment: This got me really close to the solution. I had to add an else case
elif data_set[i][0] ==2:
    out.append(data_set[i])

Comment: @Jason I thought you only wanted the first 2 after a 1, check the updated version if you need all 2